# Using the total of a column of the queried table in a case when (Hive)

Tags: sql, hive, case

Simplified example:

In **hive**, I have a table  `t` with two columns:

```
Name, Value
Bob, 2
Betty, 4
Robb, 3
```

I want to do a `case when` that uses the total of the Value column:

```
Select
    Name
    , CASE 
        When value>0.5*sum(value) over () THEN ‘0’
        When value>0.9*sum(value) over () THEN ‘1’
        ELSE ‘2’
        END as var
From table
```

I don’t like the fact that `sum(value) over ()` is computed twice. Is there a way to compute this only once. Added twist, I want to do this in one query, so **without declaring user variables**.

I was thinking of scalar queries:

```
With total as
 (Select sum(value) from table)
Select 
    Name
    , CASE 
         When value>0.5*(select * from total) THEN ‘0’
         When value>0.9*(select * from total)THEN ‘1’
         ELSE ‘2’
         END as var 
From table;
```

But this doesn’t work.

**TLDR**:  Is there a way to simplify the first query without user variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about that.  Let the optimizer worry about it.  But, you can use a subquery or CTE if you don't want to repeat the expression:

```
select Name,
       (case when value > 0.5 * total then '0'
             when value > 0.9 * total then '1' 
             else '2'
        end) as var
From (select t.*, sum(value) over () as total
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Nice query to avoid the repetition ! Concerning your comment about the optimizer, do you know how I can check/know that it doesn't compute it several times (my table is pretty big).

Answer (score 0):

Cross join a subquery that fetches the sum to the table:

```
Select
    t.Name
    , CASE 
        When t.value>0.9*tt.value THEN '1'
        When t.value>0.5*tt.value THEN '0'
        ELSE '2'
        END as var
From table t cross join (select sum(value) value from table) tt
```

and **change the order** of the WHEN clauses in the CASE expression because as they are, the 2nd case will never succeed.

Answer (score -1):

Since I/O is the major factor the slows down Hive queries, we should strive to reduce the num of stages to get better performance.

So it's better not to use a sub-query or CTE here.

Try this SQL with a global window clause:

```sql
select 
    name,
    case
        when value > 0.5*sum(value) over w then '0'
        when value > 0.9*sum(value) over w then '1'
        else '2'
        end as var
from my_table
window w as (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

In this case `window clause` is the recommended way to reduce repetition of code.

Both the windowing and the `sum` aggregation will be computed only once. You can run `explain select...`, confirming that only ONE meaningful MR stage will be launched.

Edit:
1. A simple `select` clause on a subquery is not sth to worry about. It can be pushed down to the last phase of the subquery, so as to avoid additional MR stage.
2. Two identical aggregations residing in the same query block will only be evaluated once. So don’t worry about potential repeated calculation.